# Grauert's Contractibility Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, soft-question

I am interested in reading the proof of Grauert's Contractibility Theorem, asserting that an integral compact curve in a smooth compact surface (without the projectivity assumption - this is the case I am mostly interested) is exceptional iff it has negative self-intersection.

The reference is this: Grauert, H.: Uber Modifikationen und exzeptionelle analytischen Mengen, Math. Ann. 146 (1962), 331-368.

Unfortunately I do not read german; all the sources I tried only state the result without proof (e.g. Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven) or the prove the algebraic version.

Does anyone know a reference where I can read the proof, or at least the main ideas or main steps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Fujiki has proved (in English!) the following generalization of Grauert Theorem in the analytic category.
Let $X$ be a complex space, $A$ be an effective Cartier divisor on $X$ and $f:A \longrightarrow A'$ be a proper surjective morphism. Let $L =[A]$ be the line bundle corresponding to $A$. Assume the following conditions:

_$L^*|_A$ is $f$-ample,

_$R^1f_*(L^*|_A)^{\otimes m} = 0$ for every $m>0$.

Then, there exists a birational morphism $g : X \longrightarrow X'$ such that $g|_A = f$. See Theorem 1 page 495 of [Fujiki's paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/10/2/10_2_473/_article)

In case $X$ is a compact surface and $A$ is a compact smooth (=integral) curve, the first hypothesis is equivalent to the self-intersection of the curve being negative by the normal bundle formula.
The second hypothesis is always satisfied (provided that $L^*|_A$ is ample) if $A$ is a compact smooth curve by Serre duality and the fact the a negative line bundle on a smooth compact curve has no sections.

The result above by Fujiki is the exact translation of the same result [proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970602?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by M. Artin in the category of algebraic spaces. It seems however the proof in the analytic category needs some extra-arguments, as Fujiki relies on the theory of plusri-subharmonic functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Fujiki's result looks pretty nice indeed. Anyway, it looks like this is not really a generalisation of Grauert's result, since here one starts with a surjective map from the divisor; while Grauert seems to prove that having negative-self intersection implies the existence of such a surjection (but probably in the higher dimensional case this is needed)...

Comment: @User3773 In the case of curve in a surface, there is always certainly a proper surjective map from a curve to... a point